# How can Vscode insert a whitespace automatically after autocomletion?

Tags: visual-studio-code

eg: When I type `in`, it gives the choice of `int`.When I choose the choice, it doesn't automatically add whitespace after `int`.I have to type whitespace myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no generic setting for this; it is up to the extension that provides suggestions for the language you are using.

Please file a feature request against the extension that provides these suggestions. One way a extension could implement this is by making space a commit character that accepts the current suggestion.